# Cannot get enter keypress to work in jQuery when calling click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on code that builds a div box when the user clicks on the .pTile div that does not have the .join class. The click function works, however, for accessibility reasons, I need to have the enter key also build the div when the user uses the enter key. There are multiple .pTile's on the page and more or less can be added at any time through a database. I can't seem to get the enter key function to work. Assistance would be much appreciated.

The following is the working click function the code in it is omitted as it's pretty long:

`$(document).on('click', '.pTile:not(.join)', function (e) {
 //Do stuff
});`

This is the code that I am not able to get to work:

```
    $('.pTile:not(.join)').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode || e.which) {
            $('.pTile:not(.join)').click();
            return false; }
    });
```

EDIT: I'd also like to note that the key press function does not get fired at all.

Comment: Is `$('.pTile:not(.join)')` a button (click) or an input (bind keypress)? Anyway, try `.trigger('click')` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: If there are multiple .pTile's which one is going to be build when the user clicks enter?

Comment: Each .pTile has a tab index and it is the one that the user is currently highlighted or tabbed onto.

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).on('click keypress', '.pTile:not(.join)', function (e) {`?

Comment: Just tried it, that works! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSBin with a solution: http://jsbin.com/yelomunafo/1/

Basically you add keypress to the `$(document).on('click')` part.

Comment: Yep, thanks here's the solution to my code above: Solution: 

    `$(document).on('click keypress', '.pTile:not(.join)', function (e) {
     if ((e.keyCode || e.which) != 13) {
        return false;
     }
     //Do stuff
    });`